# issue passing data back to first view controller with delegate and protocol (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So what I'm trying to do is pass a String and an Int back from one ViewController (NewCellViewController) to the previous one (SecondScreenViewController) when I close it. I added a print statement in the method in SecondScreenViewController that is supposed to receive this data, and it didn't print so I guess the method never ran. This is my code (removed some stuff to only include whats relevant):

SecondScreenViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol DataDelegate {
    func insertEvent(eventString: String, pos: Int)
}
class SecondScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, DataDelegate {


    var eventNames = ["event1", "event2", "event3"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        advance()
    }
    //DataDelegate methods
    func insertEvent(eventString: String, pos: Int)
    {
        print("if this prints, it worked")
        if pos == -1
        {
            eventNames.append(eventString)
        }
        else
        {
            eventNames.insert(eventString, at: pos)
        }
    }

    @objc func advance()
    {
        let vc = NewCellViewController(nibName: "NewCellViewController", bundle: nil)
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

NewCellViewController:

```
import UIKit

class NewCellViewController: UIViewController {


var delegate:DataDelegate?

@IBOutlet var addEventName: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func addItem() {
    insertNewEvent()   
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func insertNewEvent()
{
    let eventName = addEventName!.text
    delegate?.insertEvent(eventString: eventName!, pos: -1) //add different positions

}
```

}

Comment: How is `insertNewEvent()` on `NewCellViewController` being called?

Comment: insertNewEvent() is called when a button is pressed in NewCellViewController that calls addItem()

Comment: yup, I just printed a line from it.

Comment: You probably need to move `advance()` out of `viewDidLoad` and into `viewDidAppear`.  The controller might not be finished initializing before you call `advance()` which sets the delegate of the next controller.

Comment: Alright I did that and now the print statement in advance printed, which is definitely an improvement (I just added it to see if that was the problem) but the print statement in InsertEvent() still hasn't printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the same `controller` name as yours, just to make you understand better.

## SecondScreenViewController

```
import UIKit

class SecondScreenViewController: UIViewController {

    var eventNames = ["event1", "event2", "event3"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //advance()
    }

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        advance()
    }


    private func advance() {
        // Dont forget to add `Storyboard ID` as "NewCellViewController" on your Main.storyboard. 
        // See the image attached below.
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "NewCellViewController") as? NewCellViewController {
            vc.delegate = self
            present(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

// Better this way.
extension SecondScreenViewController: DataDelegate {
    
    func insertEvent(eventString: String, pos: Int) {
        print(eventString, pos)
    }
    
}
```

[image: Storyboard ID]

## NewCellViewController

```
import UIKit

// Better to create protocols here.
protocol DataDelegate: class {
    func insertEvent(eventString: String, pos: Int)
}

class NewCellViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: DataDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var addEventName: UITextField!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func addItem() {
        insertNewEvent()
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    private func insertNewEvent() {
        delegate?.insertEvent(eventString: "your text", pos: -1)
        
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the issue and now the test statements print, but now whenever I am on the SecondViewController screen, NewCellViewController opens and it reopens when I try to close it. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @JacquelineEdwards That is because you are calling `advance` method in `viewDidAppear` method. So, whenever `SecondScreenVirwController` view appears `advance()` method is executed. It is better to call by some action like on button click or anything else based on your requirement. And don’t forget to upvote my answer 

Comment: ohh thank you so much that fixed it! I already tried but the website says it won't display my vote because I have less than 15 reputation :/

Comment: @JacquelineEdwards No problem. happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using segue in the first VC to push the Second VC and pop the Second VC and come back to First VC. This might help you work with the delegate.
And also you can use the UserDefaults to pass and synchronize such values.

Answer (score -3):

Depending on what exactly you want to pass you could use user defaults. Not recommended by many but I feel for simple data it's really quick and effective